# Shorten way for if statements smarty, any way?

Tags: php, if-statement, smarty

Is it possible to shorten my statement like this, for example:

```
{if $name eq 'Fred' or 'Monalisa' or 'Simon'}
    Welcome Sir.
{/if}
```

If so, how would need it to look ?

Answer (score 1):

@Gaurav's answers was close, but not smarty syntax. This should work:

```
{if in_array($name, array('Fred', 'Monalisa', 'Simon')}
    Welcome Sir.
{/if}
```

On a side note, I don't think someone named Monalisa would prefer being called "Sir". :)

Comment: hehe http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&nfpr=1&sa=X&ei=D83kTavRBcmZOr6lvLcG&ved=0CBgQBSgA&q=mona+lisa+was+a+man&spell=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&biw=1280&bih=939

Comment: @Wesley van Opdorp Hm. Well, that's open for debate ;)

Comment: Hm, I think i can't use in_array in a smarty loop

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this logic in PHP:

```
<?php

// where $feminine_names is array of names, ex, array('Mary', 'Sue')
$welcome_title = in_array($name, $feminine_names) ? 'Madame' : 'Sir';

// if name is still needed in your template
$smarty->assign('name', $name);
$smarty->assign('welcome_title', $welcome_title);

?>
```

```
{*template file*}
Welcome {$welcome_title}.
```

or go the extra mile with a custom [modifier](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/plugins.modifiers.tpl):

```
<?php

function welcome_title($name){
    // where $feminine_names is array of names, ex, array('Mary', 'Sue')
    return in_array($name, $feminine_names) ? 'Madame' : 'Sir';
}

$smarty->register_modifier('welcome_title', 'welcome_title');
$smarty->assign($name);

?>
```

```
{*template file*}
Welcome {$name|welcome_title}.
```